# A question about adjoint functors:

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, natural-transformations, kan-extensions

I am trying to replicate the solution to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549291/adjoints-are-kan-extensions/3549389#comment7642681_3549389) But, in the process I got stuck. Here is my question:

> Suppose $F: C\rightleftarrows D :G$ is an adjoin pair with unit $\eta :1_C\Rightarrow GF$ and counit $\epsilon : FG\Rightarrow 1_D$ respectively. For any other functor $H :D\to C$ with a natural transformation $\alpha:G\Rightarrow H,$ is it true that $$H(\epsilon_Y)\circ\alpha_{FG(Y)}\circ\eta_{G(Y)}\stackrel{?}{=}\alpha_Y$$ for all $Y\in D$ ?

I came up with the following (commutative) naturality squares $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G(Y) @>\alpha_Y>> H(Y)\\
@V \eta_{G(Y)} V V @VV \eta_{H(Y)} V\\
GHG(Y) @>GF(\alpha_Y)>> GFH(Y)\\
@V \alpha_{FG(Y)} V V @VV \alpha_{FH(Y)} V\\
HFG(Y) @>>HF(\alpha_Y)> HFH(Y)
\end{CD}
But does not seems helpful with the question that I am having.

**Add:**

If $Y$ is in the essential image of $F,$ using the triangle identities, the required identity reduces to $\alpha_{FGF(X)}\circ\eta_{GF(X)}\stackrel{?}{=}HF(\eta_X)\circ\alpha_{F(X)}$ for some $X\in C$ and, the commutative square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
GF(X) @>GF(\eta_X)>> GFGF(X)\\
@V \alpha_{F(X)} V V @VV \alpha_{FGF(X)} V\\
HF(X) @>>HF(\eta_X)> HFGF(X)
\end{CD} confirmed it when $GF(\eta_X)=\eta_{GF(X)}$ (but I am not sure whether this true or not when $\eta_X$ is not an epimorphism). This highly suggest that the required identity can be correct.

Comment: The equation $GF\eta = \eta GF$ does not hold in general, and I suspect the other relation is false too in full generality; I'm afraid I don't understand what are you trying to reproduce exactly!

Comment: @Fosco: I am trying to establish a natural bijection $$\Phi : \text{hom}_{\text{Fun}(C,C)}(id_C, HF)\rightleftarrows \text{hom}_{\text{Fun}(D,C)}(G, H) : \Psi.$$ If $\eta^H\in\text{hom}_{\text{Fun}(C,C)}(id_C, HF),$ then the $\Phi(\eta^H)_Y=H\epsilon_Y\circ\eta^H_{G(Y)}$ produces a natural transformation in the other functor category.

Comment: And, for $\alpha\in\text{hom}_{\text{Fun}(D,C)}(G, H)$ we have a natural transformation in first functor category by $\Psi(\alpha)_X=\alpha_{F(X)}\circ\eta_X.$ Also I can prove that $$\Psi\Phi=\text{id},$$ but I am stuck at the other direction $\Phi\Psi\stackrel{?}{=}\text{id}.$

Comment: Oh, I see; we all did that exercise: look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220018/kan-exquestions

Comment: @Fosco: Thank  you for the link. I am looking through answers to that question. As you think, what is wrong in my current construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that
$$H(\epsilon_Y)\circ\alpha_{FG(Y)}\circ\eta_{G(Y)} = \alpha_Y$$
By naturality, i.e. since the square
$$
\begin{CD}
GFGY @>\alpha_{FGY}>> HFGY \\
@VG\epsilon_YVV @VVH\epsilon_YV \\
GY @>>\alpha_Y> HY
\end{CD}
$$ is commutative, this is
$$ \alpha_Y \circ G\epsilon_Y\circ \eta_{GY} $$
and by one of the triangle identity in an adjunction, this is
$$ \alpha_Y \circ \text{id}_{GY}.$$

Comment: WOw!. Thank you very much. I thought, I exhausted all related commutative squares :)